# Nancy slow to start accepting requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, initialization, nancy

I am struggling to see why Nancy doesn't accept requests for about 1 minute.  I have approximately 60 endpoints and all these initialize very quickly so all the modules get processed.

Are there common reasons for this?  Or is there a way to track down what is going on?

**EDIT**

Logging of app start up

```
App Start 4/15/2014 11:03:48 AM
App Start Complete 4/15/2014 11:03:48 AM
Bootstrap 4/15/2014 11:04:19 AM
Module 3 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 2 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:37 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:38 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:38 AM
Module 1 4/15/2014 11:06:38 AM
```

As can be seen in the times there is a delay before bootstrap and also before modules are called.

**EDIT 2**

My configuration is Nancy (v0.22.2 built from source as strong key was needed with no code changes) ASP.NET 4.5 using Web Forms.  Using Visual Studio 2013 as IDE

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup - 60 end points and all the modules are initialised but the bootstrapper is called after them? What? :)

Comment: @StevenRobbins I was mistaken have added logging to my startup will update my answer with the details

Comment: added my configuration just in case it's relevant

Comment: I have the same issue for a while and as I couldn't find any issue reported about this, I thought it was something with my setup. Are you using ServiceStack also?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I found what the issue was. The problem is with the AutoRegister feature from the TinyIoC container that Nancy uses.

Basically at startup (first request) it scans every assembly of your AppDomain to register dependencies. This process is very slow: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/643

The solution is to register your dependencies manually as indicated here: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapping-nancy

Basically you just have to create a class in your AspNet project that inherits from DefaultNancyAspNetBootstrapper and override the ConfigureApplicationContainer method:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyAspNetBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        // Register our app dependency as a normal singleton           

    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: This was indeed the reason I have a lot of large dependent assemblies.  The super duper happy path was not so happy it seems ;)

Comment: Nancy is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of slow performing of AutoRegister feature in Nancy is huge amount of assemblies and types processed. The second issue is not optimal code for such case. The current stable version of Nancy (1.4.3) has the following code https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/1.x-WorkingBranch/src/Nancy/TinyIoc/TinyIoC.cs#L3092-L3094
As result this linq expression processed for each type...
To change this behavior you can use the following class as base for your Bootstrapper.
Also you can speed up this code by exclude your 3d party assemblies in AutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies (see example in code).

In my system it helps to increase speed of auto registration by 521 times from 50 secs to 95 ms.

```
    public class AutoRegistredBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    private readonly object AutoRegisterLock = new object();
    private void AutoRegister(TinyIoCContainer container, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
    {
        var ignoreChecks = new List<Func<Type, bool>>()
        {
            t => t.FullName.StartsWith("System.", StringComparison.Ordinal),
            t => t.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.", StringComparison.Ordinal),
            t => t.IsPrimitive(),
            t => (t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Length == 0) && !(t.IsInterface() || t.IsAbstract()),
            t => t.Assembly == typeof(NancyEngine).Assembly
        };


        lock (AutoRegisterLock)
        {
            var thisType = this.GetType();
            var types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => AssemblyExtensions.SafeGetTypes(a))
                .Where(type => (type.DeclaringType != thisType)
                               && !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition())
                .Where(t => !ignoreChecks.Any(check => check(t)))
                .ToList();

            var assignebleTypes =
                types.Where(
                        type =>
                            type.IsClass() && (type.IsAbstract() == false) && (type != thisType))
                    .Select(t =>
                    {
                        // be careful with side effects in linq
                        container.Register(t);
                        return t;
                    })
                    .Where(implementationType => implementationType.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any() || implementationType.BaseType != typeof(Object))
                    .ToList();

            var abstractInterfaceTypes = types.Where(type => ((type.IsInterface() || type.IsAbstract())));

            foreach (var abstractInterfaceType in abstractInterfaceTypes)
            {
                var localType = abstractInterfaceType;
                var implementations =
                    assignebleTypes.Where(implementationType => localType.IsAssignableFrom(implementationType)).ToList();

                if (implementations.Count > 1)
                {
                    if (implementations.Count != implementations.Distinct().Count())
                    {
                        var fullNamesOfDuplicatedTypes = string.Join(",\n",
                            implementations.GroupBy(i => i).Where(j => j.Count() > 1).Select(j => j.Key.FullName));

                        throw new ArgumentException($"types: The same implementation type cannot be specified multiple times for {abstractInterfaceType.FullName}\n\n{fullNamesOfDuplicatedTypes}");
                    }

                    foreach (var implementationType in implementations)
                    {
                        container.Register(abstractInterfaceType, implementationType, implementationType.FullName);
                    }

                }

                var firstImplementation = implementations.FirstOrDefault();
                if (firstImplementation != null)
                {
                    container.Register(abstractInterfaceType, firstImplementation);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Func<Assembly, bool>> AutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies
    {
        get
        {
            return DefaultAutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies.Concat(new Func<Assembly, bool>[]
            {
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("ICSharpCode.", StringComparison.Ordinal),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("Ionic.", StringComparison.Ordinal),
                asm => asm.FullName.StartsWith("CommandLine,", StringComparison.Ordinal)
                // ADD THE REST OF 3D party libs that you don't use as dependencies 
            });
        }
    }

    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        var currentDomainAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        var ignoredAssemblies = this.AutoRegisterIgnoredAssemblies.ToList();
        var asmsForProcessing = currentDomainAssemblies.Where(a => !ignoredAssemblies.Any(ia => ia(a))).ToList();

        AutoRegister(container, asmsForProcessing);
    }

}
```